# Why is pdf_doc object empty; closure issue? Node > Sqlite > File > PDF

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I would like the below to read image files and turn them into a PDF. The files are stored on the disk, and the filename are stored in a SQLite database.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf_doc = new jsPDF();

pdf_doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello, world.');
db.all("SELECT * FROM media", function(err, rows) {
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
        var file_content = read_image_file(row.url);
        add_image_to_pdf_doc(file_content);
    });
});

function read_image_file(image_url) {
    var img_data = fs.readFileSync("./public/uploads/"+image_url);
    return img_data;
}
function add_image_to_pdf_doc(img_data) {
    pdf_doc.addImage(img_data, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
}
```

`pdf_doc` seems to be empty ("Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function") and I can't get my head around why nor how to solve this.

EDIT: this is the complete error log:

```
[2084:1102/173032:ERROR:nw_shell.cc(336)] TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.jsPDFAPI.binaryStringToUint8Array (file:///Users/j/App/dev/0002/app.nw/libs/jspdf/dist/jspdf.debug.js:2560:35)
    at Object.jsPDFAPI.addImage (file:///Users/j/App/dev/0002/app.nw/libs/jspdf/dist/jspdf.debug.js:2756:23)
    at add_image_to_pdf_doc (file:///Users/j/App/dev/0002/app.nw/controllers/main.js:122:10)
    at file:///Users/j/App/dev/0002/app.nw/controllers/main.js:113:3
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Statement.<anonymous> (file:///Users/j/App/dev/0002/app.nw/controllers/main.js:111:7)
--> in Database#all('SELECT * FROM media', [Function])
    at file:///Users/j/App/dev/0002/app.nw/controllers/main.js:110:4
[2084:1102/173032:INFO:CONSOLE(28)] "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function", source: /Users/j/App/dev/0002/app.nw/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js (28)
```

Comment: Where are you requiring `jsPDF`? What does the function do? Are you sure you are calling it correctly? Where is the error thrown?

Comment: Hi Felix jsPDF is required in index.html; when the code saves it (bypassing the images, the file contains the single hello world line).

Comment: There is no concept of `index.html` in a Node.js script.

Comment: The error is thrown in `file:///Users/j/App/dev/0002/app.nw/libs/jspdf/dist/jspdf.debug.js` in line 2560. You should have a look there.

Comment: I think that the error is actually telling you that there no such thing as `.addImage()`.

Comment: @Pointy thanks; i understood it as there is no such thing as pdf_doc; i will check .addImage()

Comment: @jrgd well I just saw your update to the question; there apparently is an `addImage()` function because it's showing up in the stack trace.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the edit; why would it not be a closure issue? I just seen you removed the closure tag

Comment: I would add `console.log(typeof file_content)` in your "read_image_file" function to see what that is. *edit* actually I bet that's the problem - `.readFileSync()` is returning a buffer object, not a string, and `.addImage()` expects the image data to be in a string.

Comment: Because you don't seem to change `pdf_doc` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by @FelixKling — there is two different things: jsPDF and Node-jsPDF. 
While one is the library (working in the browser, client side), the second is a bridge to it for Node. It appeared I got confused by the lack of documentation, also beware: fetch the archive from Github, as it seems not all distribution contains the same files…
In the hope this saves you a few hours, enjoy!